# Can CakePHP offer stricter user authentication (continuous throughout session)?

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

I am trying to create a suitable authentication check for a CakePHP service. Currently it appears that the user session is created initially during login, but never checked beyond this during a single session.

eg. Renamed the username, changing the password or ID in the user's database entry has no effect on the session.

Is there a preferred method for this type of, constantly checked, authentication? Essentially the user should be confirmed access at every request.

My current solution would involve extending the `AuthComponent` and storing a hash of the user data (including the encrypted password) and checking this at every request. I also considered storing the session ID in this same token, but noticed that CakePHP does not even use the `session_start()` function.

This functionality appears necessary for me, and I would have thought others would also require such a solution. I have yet to find Cake documentation or community solutions similar to what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use `isAuthorized()` function from **AuthComponent**. It's being called with every request.

```
public function isAuthorized($user){
    return true; //allow the user to see the page
}
```

You can `debug($user)` to see the actual data and if you want "new" information from your database, you can always get them like this:

```
public function isAuthorized($user){
    $current_user_from_database = $this->User->findById($user['id']);
    if($current_user_from_database['User']['username'] != $user['username']){
         $this->Session->setFlash('You\'ve changed the username. Please, login again.');
         $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout);
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Look at the [API](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentisAuthorized) for more info and from the PDF book. You can look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM) video about AuthComponent too. It's great.

If you need any more information or help, feel free to ask.

Btw. you have to configure **AuthComponent** in your Controller if you want `isAuthorized()` function to get called with every request.

Answer (score 0):

If `Session.timeout` will work correctly with a setting of zero minutes, you're set. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html

Comment: Thanks, I thought I may have missed some functionality in this timeout feature, but it doesn't actually do what I want. I need each request to check the current login (with a hash/token/etc) against the user database. Hence, remaining logged in if still an active user